# How to Decode and Interpret Spatial Data Encoded in Hexadecimal Format (SRID=4326) Using PHP

Tags: php, spatial, spatialite

I'm working with spatial data stored in a SQLite database, and I need help parsing and interpreting the data encoded in hexadecimal format with SRID=4326. The geometry type is described as [POLYGON, XY, SRID=4326].

Here's a sample hexadecimal representation of the spatial data: `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`

I would appreciate guidance on how to decode and interpret this hexadecimal data using PHP, considering the spatial reference system and units in degrees (SRID=4326). Specifically, I need to understand how to extract meaningful spatial information from this encoded data. Any code examples or insights would be extremely helpful!

```
<?php
require_once('vendor\geoPHP\geoPHP.inc');

$hexData = '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';


    $hexData = str_replace(["\n", "\r", " "], '', $hexData);
    
    // Convert the hex to binary
    $binaryData = pack('H*', $hexData);
    
    // Parse the WKB data
    $geom = geoPHP::load($binaryData, 'wkb');
    
    // Get the coordinates
    $coordinates = $geom->getCoordinates();
    
    // Print the coordinates
    print_r($coordinates);
    
    ?>
```

return

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Only NDR (little endian) SKB format is supported at the moment in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\geoPHP\lib\adapters\WKB.class.php:52 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\geoPHP\lib\adapters\WKB.class.php(44): WKB->getGeometry(Resource id #24) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\geoPHP\geoPHP.inc(78): WKB->read('\x00\x01\xE6\x10\x00\x00j\xCF1:Q\x11F@\x92...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\notam.php(13): geoPHP::load('\x00\x01\xE6\x10\x00\x00j\xCF1:Q\x11F@\x92...', 'wkb') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\geoPHP\lib\adapters\WKB.class.php on line 52
```

Comment: For one, `pack()` in this context converts _from_ binary, so you're just double-encoding it as hex. You probably want `unpack()`. `hex2bin()` will also do it more simply.

Comment: I did that , but l have un readable coords ! @Sammitch

Comment: Can you give any more information about the database you extracted that hexadecimal string from? Any information you have can be useful.

Comment: Dear @KIKOSoftware , l have attached the db of spatialite_history and ff_controlled_airspace that hold blob binary coords https://wetransfer.com/downloads/cbd3ba257eb099f2bd4c0c49db28ec0420240212211307/faebf2

Comment: Thank you. Now I know what the SQLite database contains: "controlled airspaces". I even know that the column you're interested in is called "geometry", and I can read the database. The "geometry" column contains a blob with binary data. You assume this is formatted in [Well-Known Binary (WKB)](https://libgeos.org/specifications/wkb/#standard-wkb), but what did you base that on? Because it is binary? You need to find out how this binary data is formatted. Just having the database doesn't explain this. Who created it, and what do they say about its content? Do you have this information?

Comment: I believe these columns typically hold 16-byte or 32-byte data. In the context of image formats, a standard JPEG usually employs 24 bits (8 bits per channel for RGB), while PNGs, with an alpha mask (RGBA), often use 32 bits. After that showcase the X, Y, Z coordinate system for blob positions, aligning with the standards set by Mapbox and Google in this regard. l found this example by foreflight but l didn't test yet. https://github.com/foreflight/fbtiles @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Olivier l am using PHP 8.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing an SQLite table which contains spatial data. The table was created with
[SpatiaLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpatiaLite) (an SQLite spatial extension).

In theory, you should manipulate the data through [specialized SQL functions](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.1.0.html#p9). For example, to retrieve the exterior of a polygon:

```sql
SELECT ExteriorRing(geometry) FROM ff_controlled_airspace
```

However, your PHP setup probably doesn't have SpatiaLite enabled, so you can't use those functions and you need to deal with the raw binary data.

Fortunately, the data format is described [here](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/BLOB-Geometry.html). The first
paragraph says:

> SpatiaLite internally stores geometry values using ordinary SQLite's BLOB columns in a format that is very closely related to WKB format, but not exactly identical.

Since the format is *not* exactly WKB, you can't use a WKB parser. However, it's not very hard to write your own parser. Here is a way to do it:

```php
function getPolygonCoords($data)
{
    // Convert from hex to binary
    $data = hex2bin($data);

    // Some validity checks
    if($data[0] != "\x00")
        throw new Exception('Invalid data');
    if($data[1] != "\x01")
        throw new Exception('Unsupported endianness');
    if($data[38] != "\x7C")
        throw new Exception('Invalid MBR_END');

    // Check that the class type is POLYGON
    $a = unpack('Vclass', $data, 39);
    if($a['class'] != 3)
        throw new Exception('No polygon found');

    // Number of points
    $a = unpack('Vlen', $data, 43 + 4);
    $len = $a['len'];

    // Point coordinates
    $coords = [];
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
        $coords[] = unpack('elon/elat', $data, 43 + 8 + 16*$i);

    return $coords;
}

$data = '0001e61000006acf313a5111464092...';
$coords = getPolygonCoords($data);
var_export($coords);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'lon' => 44.20258333333334,
    'lat' => 33.341588888888886,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'lon' => 44.29640555555556,
    'lat' => 33.19718611111111,
  ),

[...]

  32 => 
  array (
    'lon' => 44.192533750403754,
    'lat' => 33.33819806746741,
  ),
  33 => 
  array (
    'lon' => 44.20258333333334,
    'lat' => 33.341588888888886,
  ),
)
```